# Wordpress htaccess allow, deny not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
order deny,allow
deny from all
#allow from 127.0.0.1
```

This is the .htaccess I used, somehow it won't block the access for everyone, but only block certain resources (css, images etc.). Do you have any ideas ?

This should've work fine for quick debuging the site and short maintenace, I don't need any maintance web pages or so.