# "order deny,allow" only works when after rewrite rules?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site I wanted to block access to temporarily and added `order deny,allow` to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine off
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [my ip]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, it didn't work.

I tried moving it to below the rewrite rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine off
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from [my ip]
```

And is started working.

Why doesn't it work in the first example?

Comment: What exactly does work? I tried both, and both work fine in case of blocking access. However if you're setting `RewriteEngine off` after setting it to `on`, no rewrite will happen.

Comment: @martinczerwi In the first example, everyone still has access to the site. In the second example, everyone but myself is denied access, however as you mentioned the rewrite doesn't work for me and so I can't access most pages on my site.

Comment: You can remove `RewriteEngine off`, as a quick fix

Comment: Is your desktop machine Windows, or MacOS/Linux? And second is the server Linux or Windows? And your Apache version is 2.2 I suppose?

Comment: He probably use `RewriteEngine off` because of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391376/wordpress-htaccess-allow-deny-not-working).

Comment: @martinczerwi Tried removing that, but then the site is accessible to everyone again. My server is running CentOS with Apache 2.4.

Comment: Please see the 2.4 way for blocking access, it has changed since 2.2: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Comment: Martin comment is correct, Apache indeed change their stuff to something more logical. Try with `Require ip [your ip]` it may work.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress htaccess, this comments:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

Are used by Wordpress to dynamically add additional rules. If you look into `wp-admin/includes/misc.php`, there is a function named `save_mod_rewrite_rules` which handle the writing of your htaccess. Inside this function the rules are get from the `mod_rewrite_rules` method of `WP_Rewrite`, a class located in `wp-includes/rewrite.php`. If you look into that method you will see that line on the end:

```
$rules = apply_filters( 'mod_rewrite_rules', $rules );
```

It means that a filter is applied on the rules, so whatever plugin / theme can override this rules to add his own, and so add access policy. Maybe WP core add his own deny/allow rules. So maybe this is your problem here.

An alternative solution to `allow, deny` rules is to use a `RewriteCond` to throw a 403 for all IP other than your (put this on the top of your htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^[your IP]$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```